# How to consume WCF wsHttpBinding Service in application built in 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

WCF service is running with 'wsHttpBinding' Binding. The application which gonna consume WCF Service is non-wcf compliance or in other words, it is on the top of Framework 2.0 and I can't use ServiceModel in this app (since only 3.5 supports ServiceModel).

Any suggestions, how to consume above WCF Service in application built in 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work - typically. .NET 2.0 only support `basicHttpBinding,` or the new REST-style `webHttpBinding`.

You could potentially retrofit the WSE (Web Services Enhancements) - but that gets quite messy.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceModel is part of 3.0, not 3.5 - but either way I *expect* you should be able to [use WSE3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx) to connect, since this offers WS*. Jimmy Ziemowit has some thoughts on this [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2007/07/18/interoperability-between-wcf-and-wse-3-0.aspx).

In the past I've had success simply deploying System.ServiceModel.dll etc with the app onto 2.0 machines (back in the early days of 3.0); it may work for you too? A full 3.0 install is preferred, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The `wsHttpBinding` is not compatible with the ASMX-style web references used in .NET 2.0.

If you do not need message-level security, you can switch to a `basicHttpBinding`, which will make the service consumable by any client (simply use the standard Add Web Reference dialog).  If you must use WS-Security then you will either need to upgrade the client to .NET 3.0, or switch to a `customBinding` and use WSE 3.0 on the client.

(Note that WSE is no longer a supported technology and its use seems to be frowned upon by the community.  Only use this if none fo the other solutions will work for you.)